# Get textual representation of record field?

Tags: database, haskell, field, records, typesafe

Having the following record:

```
data Sleep = Sleep
   { _duration :: Maybe Int
   , _drunk :: Bool
   }
```

Is there a way to do the following:

```
deriveSomething ''Sleep

fieldName duration :: String -- "duration"
```

I need this for typesafe DB specific field updates, i.e:

```
setField connection key duration (Just 50)
```

It needs to be DB-agnostic though (thus `opaleye` etc. is out).

(If this can be achieved with a standard package like `lens` even better, but I wasn't able to find anything.)

Comment: I think `aeson` does something similar when serializing to JSON maybe you will find something useful in there

Comment: @epsilonhalbe: look at my comment below.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using `Data.Data`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
import Data.Data

data Sleep = Sleep
    { _duration :: Maybe Int
    , _drunk :: Bool
    } deriving (Typeable, Data)

fieldNames :: Data a => a -> [String]
fieldNames = constrFields . toConstr
```

Example:

```
> fieldNames (Sleep undefined undefined)
["_duration", "_drunk"]
```

You'll have to decide how you want to transform the names to database columns after that, but that should be fairly easy.

This requires a value created using a particular constructor, remember that data types can have many constructors.  There isn't really a way around this, but you could have something like

```
sleepFieldNames :: [String]
sleepFieldNames = fieldNames (Sleep undefined undefined)
```

So that you don't have to keep recalculating it.

Comment: side note: you'll need `{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}` to make that work

Comment: Unfortunately, I need a textual representation for every *specific* field, not all fields at once, i.e. I literally need something like `fieldName :: Field -> String`, where `Field` is somehow derived from the data type definition.

Comment: @PhilipKamenarsky I don't know if that'll be possible without writing some TemplateHaskell.  GHC really only sees your accessors as functions, really what you get is syntax sugar for `data Sleep = Sleep (Maybe Int) Bool; _duration :: Sleep -> Maybe Int; _drunk :: Sleep -> Bool` with the implementations just accessing the positions for you.  There's some extra magic going on, but without some TH to generate `duration` for you as some `Field` type (maybe some kind of tagged Lens?) you won't be able to.